# How to match entire string to be one of two formats with a single regular expression?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I need to validate values that can have one of two formats and am trying to do so with a single regular expression but can't figure out why it doesn't work.

The first format is exactly 17 alphanumeric characters and the expression `^[A-Za-z0-9]{17}$` correctly matches the test value `5UXWX7C56BA123456` but not the shortened value `5UXWX7C56BA12345` or the lengthened value `5UXWX7C56BA1234569`.

The second format is exactly 8 alphanumeric characters followed by asterisk or underscore ansd two more alphanumeric characters. The expression `^[A-Za-z0-9]{8}[*_][A-Za-z0-9]{2}$` correctly matches the test value `5UXWX7C5*BA` but not the shortened value `5UXWX7C5*B` or the lengthened value `5UXWX7C5*BA1`.

However when I try to combine the expressions I get unexpected results that differ, depending on which of the sub-expressions I place first. The following snippet of code demonstrates

```
var pattern1 = new Regex(@"^([A-Za-z0-9]{17})|([A-Za-z0-9]{8}[*_][A-Za-z0-9]{2})$");
var pattern2 = new Regex(@"^([A-Za-z0-9]{8}[*_][A-Za-z0-9]{2})|([A-Za-z0-9]{17})$");

var values = new string[] 
{ 
    "5UXWX7C56BA12345", "5UXWX7C56BA123456", "5UXWX7C56BA1234569", 
    "5UXWX7C5*B", "5UXWX7C5*BA", "5UXWX7C5*BA1" 
};

Console.WriteLine($"Using {pattern1}\n");
Console.WriteLine($"  {"Value",-20}{"IsMatch",-9}{"Expected",-10}");
Console.WriteLine($"  {new string('-', 37)}");
values
    .Select(x => new { Value = x, Result = pattern1.IsMatch(x), ExpectedResult = x.Length == 11 || x.Length == 17 })
    .Select(x => $"  {x.Value,-20}{x.Result,-9}{x.ExpectedResult} {(x.Result == x.ExpectedResult ? "" : "UNEXPECTED")}")
    .WithEach(Console.WriteLine);

Console.WriteLine($"\n\nUsing {pattern2}\n");
Console.WriteLine($"  {"Value",-20}{"IsMatch",-9}{"Expected",-10}");
Console.WriteLine($"  {new string('-', 37)}");
values
    .Select(x => new { Value = x, Result = pattern2.IsMatch(x), ExpectedResult = x.Length == 11 || x.Length == 17 })
    .Select(x => $"  {x.Value,-20}{x.Result,-9}{x.ExpectedResult} {(x.Result == x.ExpectedResult ? "" : "UNEXPECTED")}")
    .WithEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

producing the following results

```
Using ^([A-Za-z0-9]{17})|([A-Za-z0-9]{8}[*_][A-Za-z0-9]{2})$

  Value               IsMatch  Expected  
  -------------------------------------
  5UXWX7C56BA12345    False    False 
  5UXWX7C56BA123456   True     True 
  5UXWX7C56BA1234569  True     False UNEXPECTED
  5UXWX7C5*B          False    False 
  5UXWX7C5*BA         True     True 
  5UXWX7C5*BA1        False    False 


Using ^([A-Za-z0-9]{8}[*_][A-Za-z0-9]{2})|([A-Za-z0-9]{17})$

  Value               IsMatch  Expected  
  -------------------------------------
  5UXWX7C56BA12345    False    False 
  5UXWX7C56BA123456   True     True 
  5UXWX7C56BA1234569  True     False UNEXPECTED
  5UXWX7C5*B          False    False 
  5UXWX7C5*BA         True     True 
  5UXWX7C5*BA1        True     False UNEXPECTED
```

I hope someone will be able to point out the error in my expressions. It seems that although I am using ^ and $ to try and force the entire line/value to be matched, that somehow when longer a match is found even though there is a further unmatched character that I would have expected to cause the entire value not to match.

Although I used LINQPad to run the snippet above I see the same results from [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/).

Comment: I'm no regex whizz, but it looks to me like you have a pattern that matches the beginning *or* the end of a string, rather than 2 patterns that are at the beginning *and* the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regexps are not anchored correctly:

```
^([A-Za-z0-9]{17})|([A-Za-z0-9]{8}[*_][A-Za-z0-9]{2})$
 ^               ^ ^                                ^
```

Here, `([A-Za-z0-9]{17})` is only anchored at the start of the string  (and there can be anything after that pattern) and `([A-Za-z0-9]{8}[*_][A-Za-z0-9]{2})` is only anchored at the end of the string (and there can be anything before that pattern).

The same problem is with the second pattern, you just swapped the alternatives.

Use

```
var pattern1 = new Regex(@"^(?:[A-Za-z0-9]{17}|[A-Za-z0-9]{8}[*_][A-Za-z0-9]{2})$");
                            ^                 ^                                ^
```

Otherwise, your alternatives are not anchored on *both* sides.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5PnWaT/1).

Comment: Thank you. I understand now what I was doing wrong. Learned a bit more about regular expressions today.